Нужна ли запятая после "причём" в данном предложении?
Люди несут в ломбард фамильные драгоценности, причём (?) не забывая прихватить и серебряную посуду.

Правильно:
Люди несут в ломбард фамильные драгоцЕнности, причём не забывая прихватить и серебряную посУду.
Пояснение
Присоединительный союз ПРИЧЕМ и частица НЕ относятся к деепричастному обороту и обособляются вместе с ним. Интонация соответствующая: здесь две фразы, разделенные паузой.
Задачу решаем по правилу ПАС § 69
Ограничительные частицы только, лишь, стоящие перед 
деепричастными оборотами, включаются в их состав, и запятая 
ставится перед ними: Так и жила она без любви, только 
надеясь на нее. То же при наличии союзов, начинающих 
деепричастный оборот: По темным лестницам... ходили двое, 
потом — трое... медля и задерживаясь повсюду, СЛОВНО боясь 
приступить к делу (Фед.).

Правило касается частиц и союзов, отнесенных к обороту, но не к структуре предложения.
